# PHP module for purifying/filtering evil html

Tags: php, php-extension, htmlpurifier

I'm searching alternative to HTML [purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org)

The point is, that I need to process lots of html files on the fly and html purifier is quite heavy class - takes lots of resources and execution time. The question is maybe there is written PHP module/extension in C e.g. So it would be faster than class written in php?

Thaks in advance.

Comment: How do you define "evil" HTML in comparison to "good" HTML?

Comment: It spends all your money and makes you visit it's mother every weekend, when you have to *promise to be nice*

Comment: fab, "evil" html could have XSS, unwanted javascript etc. As this info not needed in my case, html purifier removes such threats leaving all needed formatting and so on features.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure (99%)there is no such extension for php. I'm very familiar with php and with security stuff and i think i would have known if such extension existed.